# Gravar no banco quem editou perfil

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-insert

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que cadastra funcionários de empresas.

Neste sistema tenho as tabelas funcionários e usuários.

Tabela funcionários tenho os dados

`id|nome|empresa|data_cadastro|user_view|user_edit`

Tabela usuário tenho os dados

```
id|nome|empresa
```

O Usuário ao acessar o sistema com email e senha, grava a sessão do ID do usuário.

Gostaria quando os usuários visualizassem o perfil do funcionário, grava-se o ID dele na tabela do funcionário na coluna user_view. Que no caso são pelo menos 5 usuários, para saber quem viu cada perfil.

Como gravar na tabela do funcionário? Para exibir quais usuários já viram o seu perfil. 
Mesmo função para saber se o perfil do funcionário foi editado por algum usuário.
Consigo gravar um ID por vez através de um Insert na tabela, mas como gravar vários ID em uma unica coluna, ou outra maneira que possa realizar o mesmo processo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este caso voce precisar criar uma nova tabela onde ira colocar id_funcionário e também o id_usuário e quando ele acessar voce grava nela os usuarios que visualizarão pois não tem como voce gravar vários IDs num mesmo campo.

Voce teria de criar um campo texto e salvar tipo um XML mas muitos bancos de dados isto terá um limite e voce também teria muito trabalho manual nesta segunda hipótese.

Comment: Como o fluxo de cadastros é muito grande, não seria uma alternativa viável,  pois existem muitos cadastros diários, o sistema ficaria pesado e lento.

Comment: Não voce não precisa se preocupar com isto, cria a tabela e cria as devidas chaves e pode acreditar isto não será nenhum tipo de problema quanto a velocidade e tamanho do banco de dados.

Comment: OK, vamos lá então!
Crio uma tabela chama logs
com as colunas `usuario_id | funcionario_id` - e cada vez que o usuário acessar ele grava os ID's.

Mas como faria para fazer a consulta e exibição? Busca pelo ID do funcionário exibe os Id's dos usuários, precisaria buscar quantas vezes esse ID do funcionario aparece e exibir o id do usuario.

Comment: primeiro a tabela voce cria ambos os IDs como unique pois nao precisa salvar varias vezes a mesma informação e depois basta fazer um select * from log where id_funcionario = "ID" e voce terá todos usuários ou ao contrario para saber todos os funcionários que o usuário olhou.

Comment: Varchar ou Int?

Comment: Voce criar igual a tabela original de funcionario e usuario

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o ideal seria criar uma nova tabela e nela toda vez que alguém requisitar essa pagina, você gravar o id do usuário e os dados que precisa, para localizar facilmente, tipo, você poderia criar uma tela de gerenciamento onde o usuário responsável realiza a consulta e obtêm os logs disso..  Você queria algo tipo como auditoria ? para saber quem alterou o cadastro ?

Você também tem que pensar em "crescimento" e se a empresa tiver mais usuários?Dessa forma que você passou, será necessário adicionar um outro campo na tabela e ai se ela tiver muitos usuários ficaria impraticável..  e dessa forma que você sugeriu não vejo uma forma de gravar todos os acessos... sem criar uma tabela de Logs de acesso...

Comment: não ficaria muito grande esse banco. pensei em criar mais uma coluna na tabela funcionários, com o nome do usuário, e somente inserir valor do ID, depois é so consultar no banco e fazer uma comparação entre essa coluna e o ID do usuário para exibir.

Comment: pensando dessa forma que falou... vai surgir algumas perguntas... como você vai fazer para manter a manutenção desses dados? imagine que o usuário diego, pode alterar esses dados mais de uma vez.. sem contar que  se todos editarem o registro, também não saberá qual foi a ultima alteração.. na minha opinião o ideal seria mesmo uma outra tabela.. de logs..

Comment: não haverá lentidão por que os bancos hoje são voltados para isso, vc pode indexar nas buscas, quando vc criar essa tabela, pense em criar campos como data do cadastro e data da modificação, além do id do funcionario é claro, para vc ter essas informações quando precisar..